# Scroll to the middel of screen automatically in vim

Tags: vim

When I code to the bottom side of screen in vim(**in insertmode**), how to scroll screen  to make line which I'm coding  **in  the middle of screen**  in  **insertmode** automatically .

Is there any solution? (**i know   'esc+zz+a' can do that,but can it automatically just as Emacs does** )

vim can't detect that event (code to bottom),does it？

Comment: Just to confirm, you want it so that when you open a file in Vim, it places the cursor at the bottom of the file automatically. Correct?

Comment: @Toress: It isn't clear what you want to do... please elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean by 'editing to the bottom side'? Are you already in insert mode when at the 'bottom side'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure  if it  is what  you want, but  take a  look in  the [`scrolloff`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrolloff%27)
option, which allows you to determine a  minimum offset from the bottom of the
window.

---

If  you  mean putting  the  cursor  line in  the  middle  of the  screen,  the
**normal** command  you want is  [`zz`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#zz). To access  it in insert  mode, use
<kbd>control-o</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.  You can't  do it  automatically
though.

However, an alternative is to set the  `scrolloff` option to a very high value
(999) and then the cursor line will be always centered on the screen.

Comment: maybe vim can't do that automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `set so=n` command to automatically keep n lines in between the cursor and the top and bottom edges of the screen.